# Characters in Star Wars: The Clone Wars voiced by their movie actors

Tags: star-wars, voice-acting, the-clone-wars

Besides Anthony Daniels as C-3PO, Ahmed Best as Jar Jar Binks, and Liam Neeson as Qui-Gon Jinn, are there any other characters in Star Wars: The Clone Wars who are voiced by the actor(s) who portrayed them in the movies, Episodes I-IX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [2008 film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(film)), which acted as a pilot for the series, Christopher Lee and Samuel L. Jackson reprised their respective roles as Count Dooku and Mace Windu. They did not reprise their roles in the series itself, being replaced by Corey Burton and Terrence C. Carson, but Matthew Wood did reprise his role as General Grievous.

Shmi Skywalker (sort of) makes an appearance in the Season 3 episode "Overlords", with Pernilla August reprising the role.

I don't know of any other actors who reprised their roles in either the film or the series, besides the ones you already mentioned.